# asterisk context - multiple start and ends

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to have different extension have it's own hangup agi file, I have managed to get it to load it's own start agi file, but when hanging up, it's using the first initial one.

Please help me correct my context, thank you in advance!

```
[check]
exten => _3939X.,1,AGI(start.php)
exten => h,1,AGI(END.php)

exten => _5858X.,1,AGI(58start.php)
exten => h,1,AGI(58end.php)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one `h` per `[..]` block. I think there are two things you can do here. You can either create different blocks for each extension, so they can have their own `h` extension. So maybe something like this:

```
[check]
exten => _3939X.,1,Goto(3939,s,1)
exten => _5858X.,1,Goto(5858,s,1)

[3939]
exten => s,1,AGI(start.php)
exten => h,1,AGI(39end.php)

[5858]
exten => s,1,AGI(start.php)
exten => h,1,AGI(58end.php)
```

Or use a single `end.php` script and pass an additional parameter to tell the script what to do. This way you can catch the EXT parameter in your script and then decide what actions to take based on the contents of the variable.

```
[check]
exten => _3939X.,1,Set(EXT=3939)
exten => _3939X.,2,AGI(start.php)

exten => _5858X.,1,Set(EXT=5858)
exten => _5858X.,2,AGI(58start.php)

exten => h,1,AGI(end.php|${EXT})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think with my lack of experience, I would rather do the first option as I wouldn't know how to to "catch" the EXT parameter in the end.php file. Can you show me a quick example though so I can learn? Thanks again.

Comment: You can get the parameters in php like this `$argv[1]`, read more about it here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI